# Angular Access inner component of ng-template

Tags: angular, components

Let's say we have a component called `TopComponent` with a template like this:

```
<ng-template #top>
    <inner-selector #inner></inner-selector>
</ng-template>
```

Its code is simple:

```
//... imports ...

@Component({
  // selector, styles etc
})
export class TopComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('top') topComp : NgbModal;
  // NgbModal is a type provided by some 3rd-party library
  // I can't modify it
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // let's access the #inner component from here
  }
}
```

I can access the `#top` component using this code:

```
@ViewChild('top') topComponent: TopComponent;
```

How can I access the `#inner` component from the same class?

I tried using `@ContentChild('inner')` but still getting `undefined`.

**PS.** As a workaround, I can create another component, use it inside of the `<ng-template>` and access all the necessary children from it. But can this be avoided somehow?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@ViewChild('#top')` ?

Comment: @Meir, you mean to access the `#top` component?
It works fine without `#` sign.

Answer (score 0):

The template **#top** needs to loaded into some container to exist in the DOM and get picked up by **@ViewChild**.
Easiest method is using a simple structural directive.
It the below example **NotReady** is a boolean you set to false after your ngInit has completed.

```
<div *ngIf="notReady else top"> 
    loading... 
</div>
<ng-template #top>
    <inner-selector #inner></inner-selector>
</ng-template>
```

Note the @ViewChild('top') will need to be mapped to as **static:false**, as it may not be available/exist until after ngOnInit().
#top is then searched for on each change detection cycle, useful when using conditional directives like *ngIf.

```
//... imports ...

@Component({
  // selector, styles etc
})
export class TopComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  notReady: boolean = true;

  @ViewChild("top", { static: false })  topComp : NgbModal;
  // NgbModal is a type provided by some 3rd-party library
  // I can't modify it
  
  ngInit(){
    this.notReady = false;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // let's access the #inner component from here
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use descendants @ViewChild('inner', {descendants: true}) inner: InnerSelector;

here is fill code: https://plnkr.co/edit/MtVhHuAtPXZzC7GLOidF?p=preview

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'inner-selector',
    template:'inner-selector here'
  })
  export class InnerSelector {
    myVar = 0;
  }

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div>
        <ng-template #top>
           <inner-selector #inner></inner-selector>
        </ng-template>

       <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="top"></ng-container>
      </div>
    `,
  })
  export class App {
    @ViewChild('inner', {descendants: true}) inner: InnerSelector;
    constructor() {
      this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.inner);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Julia. But it says `descendants` can't be used. Only `read: any` is allowed. Do I need a special library for that?

Comment: what version of angular -2 or 4?

Comment: I use Angular version 4.1

Comment: this example seems to be working without using "{descendants: true}" options, which seems to be invalid configuration. Compiler gives error: Argument of type '{ descendants: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ read?: any; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'descendants' does not exist in type '{ read?: any; }'.

Comment: Works even without the `descendants: true`. The important thing is using `ngAfterViewInit` **not** `onInit` or constructor.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get same error as @Algis. Also doesnt work without

Comment: descendants is not available anymore?

Comment: @Tim Yes, main trick is using `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`. Thanks!

Comment: This did not work for me. I am still unable to resolve this issue.