# Access inner component of ng-template in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using fileUpload component from primeng ( https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload ) in a modal component  ( https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples )

When Im selecting the files and display them via `ng-template`, i want to have a button that removes some of the files.

In order to do that, i need to call the `remove` method from the FileUpload component.

**My problem** is that this doesnt work.

I initially tried to use ViewChild but I get `undefined`. I can't user service, because this means i need to update the package.

**Code**

```
<ng-template #upload let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <p-fileUpload #fileUpload
                    customUpload="true"
                    (uploadHandler)="uploadMultiHandler($event)"
                    (onSelect)="onFileSelect($event)"
                    multiple="multiple"
                    accept="image/*"
                    maxFileSize="1000000"> 
        <ng-template let-file pTemplate="file">
          <div class="ui-fileupload-row">
            <div><img [src]="file.objectURL" width="50"/></div>
            <div>{{file.name}}</div>
            <div>{{formatSize(file.size)}}</div>
            <div><button type="button" icon="fa-close" pButton (click)="remove(event, file)"></button></div>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="content">
          <ul *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length">
            <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedFiles">{{file.name}} - {{file.size}} bytes</li>
          </ul>
        </ng-template>    
      </p-fileUpload>
</ng-template>

@ViewChild('fileUpload') fileUpload: FileUpload;

remove(event: Event, file: any) {
    const index: number = this.uploadedFiles.indexOf(file);
    this.fileUpload.remove(event, index);
}
```

Does anyone has any idea?
What am I doing wrong?

Links I've checked:

1. [Angular Access inner component of ng-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764536/angular-access-inner-component-of-ng-template)
2. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction
3. http://plnkr.co/edit/p40g2xGgamfCUk8pShHq?p=preview
4. https://plnkr.co/edit/xrv8Ye5c7p3h9kCgSWjD?p=preview
5. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842