# Access component nested in ngTemplate with ViewChild from Parent

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild, angular-material-7

How can you know if a lazy loaded component has been rendered? I have the following HTML:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      Panel Summary
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
      <some-component></some-component>
    </ng-template>
  <mat-expansion-panel>

  .... more panels with the same component

<mat-accordion>
```

By default the panels are closed so `<some-component>` has not been rendered yet.

Then in the typescript I have the following code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main-component',
  templateUrl: './main-component.html',
  style: ''
})
export class mainComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(SomeComponent, {static: false})
  someComponent: SomeComponent;

  onButtonClick() {
     this.someComponent.update();
  }
```

Say the panels haven't been opened yet and the user clicks on the button I get the following error:

```
mainComponent.html: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined
```

I know this is because the actual components are not loaded yet and we are trying to call its function. I want to keep lazy loading the panels to reduce the performance issues for having dynamic things in an angular materials expansion panel.

I can think of only one solution and its to not lazy load which isn't really an option. Any other solutions? Is there a way to know if ViewChild is undefined or is there a flag where viewChild will tell you if it found those components?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764536/angular-access-inner-component-of-ng-template check this one.

Comment: No luck with that as I am using Angular v8. I also looked into using ContentChild but that did not work as well.  To be specific, I tried the following ```@ContentChild(SomeComponent, {static: false}) someComponent: SomeComponent``` and I also tried ```@ViewChild(SomeComponent, {descendants: true})``` but this threw errors since ```{static: false}``` needed to be declared

Answer (score 0):

If your component isn't actually loaded then how can you expect to call the update on it? What is SomeComponent?

One thing I can think of that you can do is something like this:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel #someComponentExpansionPanel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      Panel Summary
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
      <some-component [updateOnOpen]="updateOnOpen"></some-component>
    </ng-template>
  <mat-expansion-panel>

  .... more panels with the same component

<mat-accordion>

@Component({
  selector: 'main-component',
  templateUrl: './main-component.html',
  style: ''
})
export class mainComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(SomeComponent, {static: false})
  someComponent: SomeComponent;

  @ViewChild('someComponentExpansionPanel', {static: false})
  someComponentExpansionPanel: MatExpansionPanel;

  private _updateOnOpen = false;

  get updateOnOpen(): boolean {
    return this._updateOnOpen;
  }

  onButtonClick() {
     if ( this.someComponent ) {
       this.someComponent.update();
     } else {
       this._updateOnOpen = true;
       this.someComponentExpansionPanel.open();
     }
  }
```

You'll need to implement the updateOnOpen input in the SomeComponent.

Answer (score 0):

As **@AlminiaM** mentioned:
the Expansion Panel content is lazy loaded.
It may not exist when **onButtonClick()** event occurs.

One thing to be aware of is once then expansion panel is opened (for the first time), the panel contents(SomeComponent) will then load but **after** the expansion panel (opened) event is triggered.

If the expansion panel is then closed, SomeComponent still exists in the DOM, and is still mapped to the ViewChild var.

As a result, the issue really is the very **first** someComponent.update() event
And this could be handed within your someComponent itself, called once when the child component is first loaded. For example in

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.update();
 }
```

For all other updates the parent controls the update trigger. Within the parent, check if component exists before calling the update().

```
onButtonClick() {     
  if (this.someComponent){
     this.someComponent.update();
  }
}
```

For myself, i think this is a cleaner more robust solution to AlminiaM suggestion, no need for open flag or handler checking for panel open status.